# Multiple Plots in `exams2nops()`

Tags: r-exams

I try to use more than one question with (gg)plots in an R-exam using `exams2nops()`.
However, the first plot seems to be cached and displayed instead of all further plots, too.

**Edit:**
with "more than one question" I meant an exam with several questions containing plot *per person* and each of them with randomized differences *between* persons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The templates available on the R/exams web page provide several examples how to include randomized graphics in the exercises. As a concrete example see: http://www.R-exams.org/templates/scatterplot/.

This uses base graphics for producing the scatterplot. If you want to use `ggplot2` instead you can replace the "scatterplot" chunk `plot(x, y)`, e.g., with:

```
d <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
library("ggplot2")
theme_set(theme_minimal())
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()
```

Both yield the desired randomized output.

Comment: Thanks @Achim for the link to the templates!
Meanwhile I figured out that the error was caused by multiple empty chunk labels.